# DataFrame and DataSet - converting values to <k,v> pair

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

[Sample Input (black coloured text) and Output (red coloured text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz6aj.jpg)

I have a DataFrame (one in black), how can I transform it to one like in red?
**(column number, value)**

[Image is attached]

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load("file:/home/hduser/Desktop/Demo.csv")

case class Employee(EmpId: String, Experience: Double, Salary: Double)

val ds = df.as[Employee]
```

I need the solution in both DataFrame and DataSet way.

Thank you in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a structure you want when you say  pair. check if below code gives your expected output.

With DataFrame:

```
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val data = Seq(("111",5,50000),("222",6,60000),("333",7,60000))
val df = data.toDF("EmpId","Experience","Salary")

val newdf = df.withColumn("EmpId", struct(lit("1").as("key"),col("EmpId").as("value")))
  .withColumn("Experience", struct(lit("2").as("key"),col("Experience").as("value")))
  .withColumn("Salary", struct(lit("3").as("key"),col("Salary").as("value")))
  .show(false)
```

output:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|EmpId   |Experience|Salary    |
+--------+----------+----------+
|[1, 111]|[2, 5]    |[3, 50000]|
|[1, 222]|[2, 6]    |[3, 60000]|
|[1, 333]|[2, 7]    |[3, 60000]|
+--------+----------+----------+
```

With Dataset:

First you need to define case class for new structure otherwise you can't create a dataset

```
case class Employee2(EmpId: EmpData, Experience: EmpData, Salary: EmpData)
case class EmpData(key: String,value:String)

val ds = df.as[Employee]
val newDS = ds.map(rec=>{
  (EmpData("1",rec.EmpId), EmpData("2",rec.Experience.toString),EmpData("3",rec.Salary.toString))
})
val finalDS = newDS.toDF("EmpId","Experience","Salary").as[Employee2]
finalDS.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+------------+
|EmpId   |Experience|Salary    |
+--------+--------+------------+
|[1, 111]|[2, 5]  |[3, 50000]  |
|[1, 222]|[2, 6]  |[3, 60000]  |
|[1, 333]|[2, 7]  |[3, 60000]  |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much Naveen!! :)
Yes please, show me how can the column name be changed in case of DataSet.